# Are offline google maps used device wide?

Tags: google-maps, cache, offline, offline-map

If you save an area on google maps on an android device, will other apps that use the maps api, pull data from this cache if it's available? Or is it separated and doesn't know that it exists?

I ask this question because of a reddit post that popped up about Pokemon GO:
https://www.reddit.com/r/pokemongo/comments/4s875y/i_wish_i_could_buy_this_guy_a_beer/

Comment: No. Other apps on your phone use the Google Maps API, not the Google Maps App itself. Therefore it doesn't have access to the content that is stored in your Google Maps local directory. In your above link, I also see people saying that "Pokémon Bio is loading much fast too" which doesn't make sense because Google Maps has nothing to do with it...unless the Pokémon Go app stores information of your local area. In this case, this would still be the Pokémon Go app, not Google Maps.

Comment: @MR04 Okay, I figured it may be legit if the maps api is integrated much more tightly into the OS. You should consider posting an answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no cross-app sharing of map information.

Firstly, there is a privacy concern - If Google allowed other apps to know your Google Maps offline areas (or infer them, for that matter), it would be possible for nasty apps to work out where you live and to sell that information.

Sadly, Google don't provide an 'offline maps' API to developers. I have found this frustrating when developing apps.

Unfortunately, Google have little motivation to encourage offline device usage - they make their money from their online services, especially advertising.